# Could not find method providedCompile() for arguments [org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:7.0.37]

Tags: rest, tomcat, gradle, war

I am trying to run `gradlew tasks` to build a http web service rest endpoint war project that runs on tomcat, but I am getting error after error. The current error is in the below line

> What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
>
> > Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:8.5.0 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency log4j:log4j:1.2.16 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency commons-io:commons-io:2.5 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.1 because no
> >     repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.1 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1 because no
> >     repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency javax.transaction:jta:1.1 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.5-5 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.24 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.24 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency asm:asm:3.1 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.2 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.2 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.15 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.15 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.15 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.15 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.15 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.1 because no repositories are
> >     defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1 because no repositories are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified
> >     Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:7.0.37 because no repositories
> >     are defined.   Required by:
> >           :mnoxwebserviceendpoints:unspecified

**My Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat-base"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven { 
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' 
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'
    }
}    
configurations { providedCompile }

    dependencies {
        providedCompile   'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:7.0.37'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'

        compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.0'
        compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.6.1'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.6.1'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.6.1'
        compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version: '2.4'
        compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
        compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.2.5-5'
        compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: '2.2'
        compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.24'
        compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.24'
        compile group: 'asm', name: 'asm', version: '3.1'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version: '1.9.2'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.9.2'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.2'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-xc', version: '1.9.2'
        compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-client', version: '1.15'
        compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-core', version: '1.15'
        compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.15'
        compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version: '1.15'
        compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-servlet', version: '1.15'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.jettison', name: 'jettison', version: '1.1'
        compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'jsr311-api', version: '1.1.1'
        compile files('mylocaljarfiles')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
jar {
    baseName='endpoints'
    from ('bin')
}
```

Comment: Why is your `dependencies` section in your `buildscript` section?

Comment: Good observation, I removed it. But now am getting `Plugin with id 'com.bmuschko.tomcat-base' not found.`

Comment: so there's usually two dependencies sections in a build.gradle file. One goes in the buildscript section, and contains all the dependencies of the buildscript itself. The plugin dependency for instance goes there as `classpath`. All the dependencies that your code needs, goes in the outside dependencies section usually as `compile`

Comment: I am getting a different error now.. I have edited the question with your recommendations and the new error

Comment: putting the repositories out side worked..  @RaGe please add an answer..

Comment: As with dependencies, there are also two repositories section, one for the buildscript and one for your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are often **two** `repositories` and `dependencies` sections in build.gradle. One set is completely contained inside the `buildscript{}` section and these dependencies and the repositories to find them in, apply to only the code in the build.gradle script itself. These are often gradle plugins and sometimes dependencies you use for custom build code.

Your application code dependencies are declared in a separate set of `repositories` and `dependencies` sections:

```
apply plugin: 'com.foo.bar'

buildscript{
    repositories{ //buildscript repos
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies{ //buildscript dependencies
        classpath 'com.foo:bar:1.0'
    }
}

repositories{ //repos for code
    jcenter()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'code:dependency:1.0'
    testCompile 'testcode:dependency:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Ihave upvoted your anwer and awarded you the bounty.. thanks